# Couldn't Import .sql File to New Database in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.
I tried many times to import data from the .sql file to my database but after I exited from MySQL shell. every change doesn't apply to my database.

I used this command to import :

```
mysql> use my_database_name;

mysql> source /home/maghsood/Downloads/db_name.sql
```

after doing this command and see tables show me tables correctly but after I exit my MySQL shell. and log in again don't show any tables for me.

```
sudo MySQL -u root -p 

mysql> use my_database_name;

mysql> show tables;

output : Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: What do you get if you show tables instead of show my_database_name?

Comment: Looks like non-committed transaction was rollbacked. Try explicit COMMIT after loading .SQL file.

Comment: I edited my question but it doesn't show any tables.

Comment: @Akina I'll try it thanks

Comment: Please show the first part of the contents of `db_name.sql`, up to and including the first `INSERT` statement.

Comment: @Akina I committed after changes but the result is the same. and auto-commit is true in my MySQL thanks anyway.

Comment: Test: a) Open one shell, import, check tables and data existence, but don't close. b) Open one more shell, check tables and data existence from it.

Comment: thanks @kmoser I checked .sql file and there were an exception there I solve it :)